# Using a string in if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x

Can anyone explain what check is being performed on `word` in the statement `if word:` in the following code?

```
def simplify(text, space=" \t\n\r\f", delete=""):
    result = []
    word = ""
    for char in text:
        if char in delete:
            continue
        elif char in space:
            if word:
                result.append(word)
                word = ""
        else:
            word += char
    if word:
        result.append(word)
    return " ".join(result)
```

Comment: Is that `=+` some cool new Python 3 thing or will that result in a `TypeError`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A non empty string in python is always True, otherwise False. So if word is still your empty string it will be False, otherwise True.

Comment: You can generalize this in terms of the special methods [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) and [`__len__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__). It falls back on `str.__len__`, since `str` doesn't define `__bool__`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try it for yourself in Python's REPL (that's one of the beauty of the language and languages in its class):

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> word = ""
>>> if word: print "I'm here"
... 
>>> word = "not empty"
>>> if word: print "I'm here"
... 
I'm here
```

Comment: This seems a bit contrived. If he knew what to test (empty vs non-empty string) he'd probably not be asking the question. :)